# "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." format "yyyy-MM-dd" how i can use this format

Tags: c#, asp.net

My script from txtdate;

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" AutoComplete="off"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('[id*=txtDate]').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        format: "yyyy/MM/dd",
        language: "tr"
    });
});
</script>
```

I try to use format in my date time

```
DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate1.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", new CultureInfo("en-US")).AddDays(7);
```

I get an error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

But this format works:

```
DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate1.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US")).AddDays(7);
```

How can I use format "yyyy-MM-dd" ?

Comment: The format is unmatched from your datepicker value: "yyyy/MM/dd".

Comment: What *is* the actual value of txtDate1.Text?

Comment: this value of txtdate1.text 11/04/2021

Comment: So why would you expect "11/04/2021" (month, day, year, using a slash separator) to match the pattern you've specified of "year, month, day using a dash separator"?

Comment: "How can I use format "yyyy-MM-dd"" - by changing your JavaScript to *send* that format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS it looks like you expecting string that contains date in this format
`format: "yyyy/MM/dd`
So both of your parsing should be invalid.

So how this **DateTime.ParseExact** works:

You have input string that can be formatted in different ways.

**DateTime.ParseExact** is defined:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact (string s, string format, IFormatProvider? provider);
```

docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0

- So what it means is that **s** is input date string that you want to parse.
- String **format** tells the method what format is your input string.
- And **provider** is an object that supplies culture-specific format information about s.

So example:

`var dateString = "11/04/2021";`

If you do:

```
 var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Your `date` will be `11th April 2021`

But if you do:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Your `date` will be `4th November 2021`

Addition:

If you try this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM-dd-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

You will be thrown `System.FormatException: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."` simply because string is **"11/04/2021"** and you telling your parser to expect **"MM-dd-yyyy"**
Hope its clearer now.